# Equivalents to SQL Server TOP

Tags: sql, database, keyword

In SQL Server, TOP may be used to return the first n number of rows in a query. For example,

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM users ORDER BY id
```

might be used to return the first 100 people that registered for a site. (This is not necessarily the best way, I am just using it as an example).

My question is - What is the equivalent to TOP in other databases, such as Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc? If there is not an equivalent keyword, what workarounds can you recommend to achieve the same result?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595123/is-there-an-ansi-sql-alternative-to-the-mysql-limit-keyword

Comment: Technically, yes. But only if you know the mysql LIMIT keyword which I did not at the time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To select first `100` rows:

`MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
ORDER BY
        column
LIMIT 100
```

`Oracle`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*
        FROM    table
        ORDER BY
                column
        )
WHERE   rownum <= 100
```

Note that you need a subquery here. If you don't add a subquery, `ROWNUM` will select first `10` rows in random order and then sort them by `column`.

To select rows between `100` and `300`:

`MySQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE
ORDER BY
        column
LIMIT   100, 200
```

`PostgreSQL`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
ORDER BY
        column
OFFSET 100 LIMIT 200
```

`Oracle`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORER BY column) AS rn
        FROM    table
        )
WHERE   rn >= 100
        AND rownum <= 200
```

Note that an attempt to simplify it with `ROWNUM BETWEEN 100 AND 200` (as opposed to `rn BETWEEN 100 AND 200` in the outer query) will return nothing in `Oracle`!

`RN BETWEEN 100 AND 200` will work in `Oracle` too but is less efficient.

See the article in my blog for performance details:

- [**Oracle: ROW_NUMBER vs ROWNUM**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/)

Comment: why isn't this standardized? what @ocdecia posted is not clear at all, I think mysql and postgre notations are the best

Comment: @Pablote: because Oracle is older than I am, and Sybase (which SQL Server is based on) is only 4 years younger. There were no standards that time. And by the time standards appeared, way too much code already existed to change anything.

Comment: @Pablote: what @ocdecio posted are anayltic functions, not recordset limiting. They can be used to limit recordsets, but it's not their main goal.

Comment: @Quassnoi - that's correct, but it belongs to SQL3 standard window functions and is therefore IMO better than using each vendor's specific syntax.

Comment: @ocdecio: ROW_NUMBER is always less inefficient than ROWNUM in Oracle and sometimes less efficient than TOP in MS SQL.

Comment: For your MySQL example, could you indicate which is limit and which is offset?

Answer (score 6):

For Postgres and MySQL it's the LIMIT keyword.

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is standard SQL (Oracle and SQL Server implement it). This is an example of returning up to 100 rows:

```
        SELECT ID_CONTROL FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID_CONTROL) 
        ROWNUMBER, ID_CONTROL FROM IWS_CONTROL WHERE 
        CURRENT_STATE = 15 AND CURRENT_STATUS=0) A WHERE ROWNUMBER <= 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Anywhere, it's the same as SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM users ORDER BY id
```

You can even start in the middle of the result set if you want:

```
SELECT TOP 100 START AT 50 * FROM users ORDER BY id
```

gets the 50th through 150th rows of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

```
LIMIT 100
```

as in

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY bar LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RANK() and DENSE_RANK() in Oracle. [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/07-jan/o17asktom.html) is a link to AskTom website explaining how to to pagination and top-n queries with DENSE_RANK in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle:

```
select * from (select * from foo ORDER BY bar) where rownum < 100
```

With a nice explanation on how to make it work in [AskTom](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html).

In Ingres the same query would by:

```
select First 100 * from foo ORDER BY bar
```

Ingres question was already answered in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602/how-to-limit-result-set-size-for-arbitrary-query-in-ingres) before.

Comment: So, the query should actually by:

  select * from (select * from foo order by bar) where rownum  <100

to get the top 100 after the ordering...

Comment: Oops, that should be <=100 as rownum starts from 1

Answer (score 1):

In DB2 you would make your query look like this:

SELECT * FROM tblData **FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY**;

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you want to use a TOP-N query.

For example:

```
select  *
  from  (SELECT  *
           FROM  foo
          where  foo_id=[number]
       order by  foo_id desc)
 where  rownum <= 3
```

This will get you the top three results (because I order by desc in the sub query)