# Restrict number of rows retrieved in Ingres select query

Tags: sql, ingres

I want to know if there is a way to select a subsequent bunch of rows in select query in Ingres. For example, the first 500 rows can be selected by using the select first 500 from tablename, but if I want to select rows 501 to 1000, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the OFFSET clause in the following way:

```
SELECT col_name 
FROM table 
WHERE col_name = 'value' 
OFFSET m FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY
```

For example

```
SELECT *
FROM table  
OFFSET 501 FETCH FIRST 500 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use :

```
SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT FIRST 10 field1, field2 FROM table
```

I tested it in Ingres 9.2 and it works

See also:
[How to limit result set size for arbitrary query in Ingres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602/how-to-limit-result-set-size-for-arbitrary-query-in-ingres)

Comment: Thanks Adrian. we are upgrading to Ingres9.2 next year so i will be able to to amke it work then.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select top 1000 * from table;
```

works perfectly in 10.0

Answer (score 0):

you can try restricting the row number using the `rownum` var:

```
SELECT * from TABLE
WHERE rownum <=500
```

i haven't tested it on your problem, but it should work fine :

```
SELECT * from TABLE
WHERE rownum >500
AND rownum <= 1000
```

Comment: Ingres does not have a rownum column. There is a hidden tid column however the value contained is based on the page number and it's position within the page.