# ODBC connection using php connection with ingres

Tags: php, odbc

I am using the php odbc connection  to connect the ingress database it no sql database.Here I want to use the **limit or top or first** command in the query.I have tried with all options it gives the syntax error.kindly suggest any one regarding this.

my query is

1. select TOP 10 * from emp;
2. select * from emp limit 10; & select * from emp limit 0,10;
3. select * from emp first(10);

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select First 10 * from myTable
```

[Reference-1](http://docs.ingres.com/sqlref/Selectinteractive)

[Reference-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602/how-to-limit-result-set-size-for-arbitrary-query-in-ingres)